# Is it possible to wrap default android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I am trying to implement extension to keyboard (input method).
I wonder if there is a defualt keyboard resourses/implementation which I can wrap. Eg if user presses 'Default kbd' block 'qwerty' is shown as default android keyboard, and i i press 'my extension' block `qwerty` replace with extension. 
*note:* I looking for the way (if exists) to create custom input method without rebuilnd defualt keyboard, not the app only keyboard cover like this https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own custom keyboard to display such scenario. On your keyboard you can maintain two different layer at a time. So all you would need is `KeyboardView` class:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:keyBackground="@color/background_color"
    android:keyTextColor="#37474F"
    android:keyTextSize="20sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:background="#ECEFF1"/>
```

Resources to follow:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

Though these examples would display example only on key representation you can easily add any xml as a keyboard layer.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do unfortunately is not possible.

Try to find an open source keyboard implementation and build upon it.
See [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/thuannv/LatinIME) for a working implementation of the default LatinIME, use it as your base.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next trick:

1. Detect the moment of the keyboard being shown.
2. Evaluate the bottom of your layout.
3. Show your UI just above the keyboard.
4. Hide your UI on the moment of keyboard hiding.

"2" and "3" are slightly different depending on the keyboard showing mode (adjustResiz or adjustPan).

Usefull links:

- https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft